# How to arrange files in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

How do you arrange model files and controller files in their respective folders? 
And what do you have to write in the `__init__.py` file?

Currently I have all my models and controllers in the root folder of the module like this

```
addons\
-->mymodule\
   -->views\
      -->view.xml
   -->__init__.py
   -->__openerp__.py
   -->models.py
   -->controllers.py
```

I have tried like this

```
addons\
-->models\
   -->models.py
```

And then import the `models.py` using this inside `__init__.py`

```
from models import models
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addons\
   ->yourmodule\
      ->controllers\
         ->__init__.py
         ->controllers.py
      ->models\
         ->__init__.py
         ->modelname.py
      ->__init__.py
      ->__openerp__.py
```

Content of the init.py in the controllers folder:

```
from . import controllers
```

Content of the controllers.py in the controllers folder:

```
from openerp import http
```

Content of the init.py in the models folder:

```
from . import modelname
```

Content of the init.py in the module folder:

```
from . import controllers
from . import models
```

Content of the openerp.py in the module folder: List of all your xml files ([Instruction](http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/docs/__openerp__.py.html))